# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using AJAX calender extender with a textbox, And i want to disable past dates, so that user do not able to select those, which are less than today's date. My code is as follows

In .aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" ontextchanged="txtFromDate_TextChanged"        AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFromDate">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and on .cs page

```
protected void txtFromDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);
        if (dt1 < DateTime.Now)
        {
            //Response.Write("you can not choose date earlier than today's date");
            txtFromDate.Text = null;
        } 
    }
```

But i am getting the following error:
 **System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**.

 and is there any way that i can make those date unclickable so that user cant choose from them using startDate and Enddate attributes, or by some other means, I also tried those but again i got error that these are not supported. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For starters you want to want to use tryparse, which won't throw the error but simply return false if the string cannot be converted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your `Date`'s format is "yyyy/MM/dd":

```
String[] date = typedDate.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' });
Datetime dy = new DateTime(int.Parse(date[0]), int.Parse(date[1]), int.Parse(date[2]));
```